# Initializing json object with string having regex

Tags: regex, json

I want to initialize the json object with the given string

```
String str = "{regex:/^(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^:*()#%`~*^&+={}| >&quot;|\\]*$/,'value':10}";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
    System.out.println("Result ######### "+jsonObj);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It shows error because of special characters for key regex, Is there any other possiblities to achieve this?

Comment: That string isn't [JSON](http://json.org/), JSON doesn't know what `/.../` means.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding single quotes around your `regEx`.

```
String str = "{regex:'/^(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^:*()#%`~*^&+={}| >&quot;|\\]*$/','value':10}";
```